# django reusing form template to display data?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates

So I have about a dozen forms for user input like this that I've created over some time now (Had to manually do because the forms have to look a certain way). Example:

```
<div class="">
    <h4 class="row">Provide data for Installation Report</h4>
    <form action="" method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <div>
            <p class="row">Onsite Installation (Completed by Installer)<br> Installer must complete one “Service Provider” Section for each unit installed</p>
            <div class="row z-depth-2 input-grouping">
                <div class="col s12 m12 l6 ">
                    <input class="datepicker" id="id_installationDate" name="installationDate" type="text" required />
                    <label for="id_installationDate">Date of Installation</label>
                </div>
                <div class="col s12 m12 l6 ">
                    <input id="id_deliveryOrder" maxlength="255" name="deliveryOrder" type="text" />
                    <label for="id_deliveryOrder">Delivery Order</label>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row z-depth-2 input-grouping">
                <div class="col s12 m12 l6 ">
                    <input id="id_unitSerialNumber" maxlength="255" name="unitSerialNumber" type="text" required />
                    <label for="id_unitSerialNumber">Unit Serial Number</label>
                </div>
                <div class="col s12 m12 l6">
                    <input id="id_unitHours" name="unitHours" step="0.01" type="number" required />
                    <label for="id_unitHours">Unit Hours</label>
                </div>
            </div>
And so on ...
```

This form for example, saves data to `InstallationReport` model.

Now I need to display an `InstallationReport` object somewhere. It'd be great if I don't have to copy-paste the html in the form above (and then bind data). Instead, if I can just use the form itself to show the object, it'd be easier for me.

Is there a way for me to do this without too much trouble?

Comment: Maybe use django model forms for this? Or you make a snippet out of this HTML and include this snippet wherever necessary. I think it will be better to use model form for this.

Comment: @rajkris: I already use model forms.

Comment: I cannot see you using the django form in the above code.